# Get file from a php page with Python

Tags: python

i want to download a subtitle from http://www.turkcealtyazi.org/sub/670264/fantastic-beasts-and-where-to-find-them.html

There is a button that redirects to "down.php" and starts the download.This the is button's html code:

```
<form  method="post" action="/down.php" >
        <div style="text-align:center">
                <input type="hidden" name="idid" value="670441">
                <input type="hidden" name="altid" value="670264">
                <input type="hidden" name="sidid" value="8a8ed56bafbf7df631e367f1289eb046">

                <button type="submit" class="altIndirButton">
                    <span class="altIndir1"></span>
                </button>
        </div>
</form>
```

This is my code, it downloads and saves the file without an error but the downloaded zip file is always  corrupted.

```
import requests

def saveDisc(text):
    f = open("subtitle.zip","w")
    f.write(text)
    f.close()

data = {'idid': "670441", 'altid':"670264",'sidid':"8a8ed56bafbf7df631e367f1289eb046"}
response = requests.post('http://www.turkcealtyazi.org/down.php', data=data)

print response.headers.get("Content-disposition")  #output=attachment; filename=670264-Fantastic-Beasts-and-Where-to-Find-Them-2016-1CD-23.976fps-TR-29kB-TurkceAltyazi-org.zip
print len(response.content) #output=30539

saveDisc(response.content)
```

Why my zip-file is corrupt?

[Downloaded files comparison, archive is corrupt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQnw5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file in w+ mode, so it interprets it as text file!

> Python on Windows makes a distinction between text and binary files;
>   the end-of-line characters in text files are automatically altered
>   slightly when data is read or written. This behind-the-scenes
>   modification to file data is fine for ASCII text files, but it’ll
>   corrupt binary data like that in JPEG or EXE files.

Use the mode wb+ for binary files.
Like this :

```
f = open("subtitle.zip","wb+")
```

Comment: Thank you so much i was tring to fix this for hours. It took only 30 sec for you, you are awesome.